# undo export cflags and export cxxflags change

Tags: 12.04, compiling, make

I recently mistakenly executed some commands I'd like to undo.

In an attempt to compile flightgear 2.8 for Ubuntu 12.04 I stupidly used the following commands from and OS/X guide:

```
export CFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -arch i386 -arch x86_64"
```

and `export CXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -arch i386 -arch x86_64"`

as well as `cmake . -DJPEG_FACTORY=1 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local`

I've checked ~/.bashrc and nothing was changed there. Where were these changes written? How can I undo them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was written to the CMakeCache.txt file within the source directory I was working in. Unfortunately I thought I checked all the cmake files but I was in an older source directory at the time.

As far as I can tell no system changes were made when executing those environment exports...rather, only changes within the directory source I was working in. Please correct me, if I am wrong.